How do I capture in a register the number of search matches?
I understand the Vim search/count command ... s/word//gn
I want to add the count result, i.e. the number of matches, to the file. In a file of 2500 sentences, one sentence each line.
I want to:

Cycle through each sentence,
Count the number of 'words' in each sentence and then
Add the resulting number to the file. i.e.: one number at the end of each sentence/line reflecting the number of words that sentence contains.

I want only the number of matches. Search of s/word//gn reports: 8 matches on 1 line.
I want to capture only that first number 8.

Do you have still something open in your question? How can we help your further? Otherwise maybe could you accept one of the solution using the v button next to the arrow voting buttons. It allow the question to rest :-)

I would do:
g/^/execute 'normal A ' . len(split(getline('.'), '\W\+'))

Where:

g/^/ loop on every line
len(split(getline('.'), '\W\+') count the number of word
'normal A ' . len(split(getline('.'), '\W\+') append the number of words at the end of the line


Instead of trying to capture the result from running an :s command as others have suggested, I'd recommend to use the searchcount().
This is from the help:
This returns a Dictionary. The dictionary is empty if the
previous pattern was not set and "pattern" was not specified.
key           type            meaning ~
current       |Number|        current position of match;
                              0 if the cursor position is
                              before the first match
exact_match   |Boolean|       1 if "current" is matched on
                              "pos", otherwise 0
total         |Number|        total count of matches found
incomplete    |Number|        0: search was fully completed
                              1: recomputing was timed out
                              2: max count exceeded

Try this example on the command line:
:echo searchcount(#{pattern: '\<word\>'}).total


You can use the expression execute('s/word//gn') to capture the output ("8 matches on 1 line" in your case), then you can use a split() to split the words of that line and use array indexing to pick the first word only, as in:
:echo split(execute('s/word//gn'))[0]

If you want to append that to the end of each line, you can use a :s with an expression in the replacement part. I'm also adding a /e flag so it doesn't return E486: Pattern not found: word and a :silent! to the start so it doesn't error out with trying to find the first element of an empty array (without the :silent! you get E684: List index out of range: 0 errors for every line that doesn't match the pattern.)
Also, the ' '.. adds a space to the start of the expression, so that you add a space and an 8 or whatever the count is to that line. Lines that do not have any word matches will not get anything appended to them.
:silent! %s#$#\=' '..split(execute('s/word//egn'))[0]#

